# How to stop window controls appearing in menu bar and apllication

Tags: 14.04, window-manager

[image]I have just installed ubuntu 14.04, when an application is maximised the windows controls appear in both the application and menu bar in unity. I have it set to just appear in the menu bar at all times. How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: Could you elaborate? For example, what program is this? Does Libreoffice do it? Can we have a screenshot?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes it happens in all applications including libre office (see screenshot) it doesn't occur straight after login but I haven't been able to ascertain what appears to trigger it, but maybe after the screen is locked.

Comment: I used to get this in 12.04 and found an answer, but I'm not usre where...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When this happens to a window I have found that if I activate window spread windows key + W then come back out of window spread,that the buttons in a full screen application go back into the unity panel (menu bar).